# Failed to open the file

Tags: python, annotations, vep

I have installed vep locally on my linux. I also downloaded the caches of the reference genomes (homo-sapiens).
I would like to annotate a vcf file with vep. For this I have created a Python script.

My code is the following:

```py
import subprocess
import os

def annotate_vcf(vcf_file):
    output_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'output.csv')
    print(f"Le fichier output sera créé à l'emplacement : {output_path}")
    vep_command = f'/home/.../annotation/ensembl-vep/vep -i {vcf_file} --cache --dir_cache /home/.../.vep --fasta /home/.../.vep/homo_sapiens/109_GRCh38 --assembly GRCh38 --format vcf --vcf --pick --force_overwrite --no_escape --everything --output_file {output_path}' 
    subprocess.call(vep_command, shell=True)
    if os.path.exists(output_path):
        print("Le fichier output a été créé avec succès!")
    else:
        print("Erreur : le fichier output n'a pas été créé.")

annotate_vcf('/home/.../annotation/TSVC_variants_IonXpress_011.vcf')
```

My file is created, however it is not annotated, indeed it does not access the reference genome contained in /homo_sapiens/....
My error message is the following:

> [E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open the file
> /home/.../.vep/homo_sapiens/109_GRCh38
> Segmentation fault

My file exists, I have all the rights on it and on the parent and child files. The path to the folder is correct. The folder does not appear to be corrupted either as I can access its contents.

I don't know what to do, has anyone experienced this or have an idea of what to do?